# Multiple requests are being made from service worker to cache a resource

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache

As I'm working on building progressive web apps. We are facing weird behaviour for service worker.

```
1. Clear cache and unregister service worker
2. Go to www.example.com
3. Examine the network calls for resources (JS/CSS)
```

Expected result:
Only single network request should go for one resource.

Actual result:
Two network requests are being made for each of the resource [[image: SCREENSHOT[1]]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your service worker code.

Comment: I'm using sw-precache for static resources and also using toolbox for dynamic. Paul, Is this because sw registers in parallel and make network request separately for pre-cached items ? I can share my code with you if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing in `sw-precache` fetching the resources to populate its caches. That happens independently of the initial request made by the controlled page. It's a fairly common model, whether or not you're using `sw-precache`.

(As an aside, I see that you're explicitly versioning your JS and CSS resources, which is great. You'll notice that `sw-precache` appends a cache-busting header to its precaching requests right now, meaning that they'll always go against the network instead of the HTTP browser cache. The upcoming 4.0.0 release of `sw-precache`, which you can use now via the `master` branch, has a new [`dontCacheBustUrlsMatching` option](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#dontcachebusturlsmatching-regex), which allows you to opt-out of cache-busting for resources that you're explicitly versioning via filenames. Using that option means that the additional `sw-precache` request to populate its caches will be fulfilled via the HTTP browser cache, skipping a trip to the network.)